# What are the difference between actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae) and (ActionEvent e) in Java?

Tags: java, actionevent

What is the difference between `actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)` and `(ActionEvent e)` in Java?

Comment: There is no difference. You can use whatever you want for the parameter names.

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html)?

Comment: Also, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216051/what-does-actionevent-e-mean

Comment: You are free to give a variable whatever name you prefer. `e` or `ae` or `event` or `foo` or `dog`, all valid.